# Переместить запись из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы `users` и `del`, требуется из таблицы `users` переместить в таблицу `del` одну запись, у `users` есть автоинкремент. Требуется запрос переноса из `users=>del` и `del=>users`, и при этом сохранить `id`(автоинкремент).

Comment: Завести колонку `del` не вариант? апдейтить ее, вместо причудливых переносов?

Comment: по-моему @YuraIvanov дело говорит - перемещать записи в данном случае - просто тратить ресурсы и как [говорил старина Оккам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0): "Не следует множить сущее без необходимости"

Comment: Если сделать во всех запросах дополнительно WHERE на колонку del. Падает производительность на 1% 2% и более, иза того что требуется дополнительное сравнение(а ведь у 99% пользователей del будет равен false(0)) дальше, мускул будет всегда спотыкатся об эту запись. Перенося ее в другую таблицу я избавляюсь от доп проверок(а проверок с del столбцом минимум в 20 запросах, проект большой) и мускул не будет спотыкатся. Дальше например, вы задали дополнительно Where del = 0, а вы не думали что мускул найдет запись del=1 и будет дальше всю таблицу расшаркивать?

Comment: @ДенисКотляров хмм, большой проект... У вас нет нигде foreign key на юзеров? Или у вас каскадное удаление идет? Почему вы тогда сохраняете только юзеров? Холиварная тема "soft delete" vs "hard delete", но кажется ваши аргументы не учитывают некоторых нюансов...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
START TRANSACTION; 
INSERT INTO del SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 354;
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 354 LIMIT 1;
COMMIT;
```

В транзакции выполняем два запроса - первый на копирование записи с выбранным `id` из таблицы `users` в таблицу `del`. Второй - удаление записи из таблицы.

Comment: Ок, попробую, не хватает Limit:)

Comment: Мне кажется тут он избыточен, но согласен начинать запрос с LIMIT - хорошая привычка, особенно, если часто работаешь в консоли :)

Comment: Щяс пока извините, протестить не могу, занет немного другим делом. Вскоре протещю и если будет работать(а я так думаю будет) то поставлю +.

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить автоинкремент будет сложно. Например mysqldump не сохраняет состояние автоинкремента. После восстановления БД автоинкремент возьмет ближайшее число. Как вариант - использовать таблицу-нумератор users_numerator с автоинкрементом, и связать с ней users и del по id